# Difference between splice call and pop call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking at this in a codebase:

```
  let lines = data.split('\n');
  this.lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length - 1, 1)[0];
```

I am not seeing any difference in the above and this:

```
  let lines = data.split('\n');
  this.lastLineData = lines.pop();
```

is there any difference?

Comment: pop() will always remove and return the last element of the array; splice is more flexible, you can remove and return many items, from different positions... but in your specific case, they are similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `splice` to the same effect as `pop`. But you can also do a lot more with `splice`, whereas `pop` will always only remove and return the last item in an array.

There are [performance implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052782/is-splice-faster-than-shift-pop-why), so make sure to choose the appropriate method for your use case.

Comment: The performance link is for actionscript-3 not javascript or nodejs.

Comment: @JanJohansen Wow, good catch! Although I believe the implication is still the same in JavaScript runtimes?

Comment: I did a little test to mimic the same as your link and the difference is not at all the same as the actionscript tests. See http://jsben.ch/60Uv6